# How can we get conversation / message thread between customer and business using whatsapp business cloud API

Tags: whatsapp-cloud-api

I am new to this WhatsApp Business API and interested in reading or getting conversation details between customer and business.

As I was exploring APIs which meta offering us to use, I did not found from here (https://www.postman.com/meta/workspace/whatsapp-business-platform/collection/13382743-84d01ff8-4253-4720-b454-af661f36acc2) any API which is helping me to read any conversation based on conversation-id or any such kind of ids, which happened between customer and business.

Is there any such API using which we can get conversation / message-thread details?

Please correct me if I am checking right APIs which meta is offering us to use, any lead would be appriciated.

Thanks